# Unknown Error in P5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am having an issue finding the error in my code. I am making my own version of space invaders for a school project. P5 isn't showing any errors, but when I do a test run of the code, all I get is a white screen. I need an extra set of eyes for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

```
//initializes bullets
var bullets = {
    x: new Array(),
    y: new Array(),
    shot: new Array()
}
//initializes the ship
var ship = {
    x: 625,
    y: 475,
    photo: loadImage("download.png")
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1350,650);

  //bullet1
  append(bullets.x, ship.x);
  append(bullets.y, ship.y);
  append(bullets.shot, false);

  //bullet2
  append(bullets.x, ship.x);
  append(bullets.y, ship.y);
  append(bullets.shot, false);

  //bullet3
  append(bullets.x, ship.x);
  append(bullets.y, ship.y);
  append(bullets.shot, false);
}

//Controls
function updateShip()
{
    //Right movement
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
        ship.x = ship.x+ 10;
        if (ship.x >= 1350) {
            ship.x = ship.x - 11;
        }
    }
    //Left movement
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
        ship.x = ship.x - 10;
        if (ship.x <= 0) {
            ship.x = ship.x + 11;
        }
    }
    //Up movement
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
        ship.y = ship.y - 10;
        if (ship.y <= 350) {
            ship.y = ship.y + 11;
        }
    }
    //Down movement
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
        ship.y = ship.y + 10;
        if (ship.y >= 580) {
            ship.y = ship.y - 11;
        }
    }
}
function drawShip()
{
    ship.photo.resize(75,75);
    image(ship.photo,ship.x-ship.photo.width/2,ship.y+ship.photo.height/2);
}
//Drawing the bullets
function drawBullets() {
    fill(255);
    rect(bullets.x[0],bullets.y[0], 5, 10);
    rect(bullets.x[1],bullets.y[1], 5, 10);
    rect(bullets.x[2],bullets.y[2], 5, 10);
}

//Controls the bullet movement
function updateBullets() {
    bullets.y[0] = bullets.y[0] + 10;
}

//Checks if bullet is shot
function checkShoot() {
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === 32) {
        bullets.y[0] = ship.y;
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    updateShip();
    drawShip();
    checkShoot();
    updateBullets();
    drawBullets();
}
```

Comment: ? I. Can't see where this app starts from

Comment: I havent coded any HTML for it. It's in P5 which is pretty much the JS version of Processing.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Looks like there is error 'loadImage is not defined'.

Comment: Looking over things, I have moved the 2 structs in the setup() fuction and that fixed the 'loadimage not defined'. So now the background appears, but not my image.

Answer (score 0):

You should move loadImage() function into your sketch's setup() function.
Like this

```
var ship;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1350,650);
    ship = {
        x: 625,
        y: 475,
        photo: loadImage("download.png")
    }
    //something
}
```